# How to get an Ubuntu system that boots to the command line to start the GUI?

Tags: command-line, updates

As the title above, I am totally new to Linux. What I have now is a virtual hardisk with ubuntu and it started up as CLI. What I want to do is enable the graphic mode and able to switch it flexibly.

So, I wanted to install `ubuntu-desktop` due to the fact that Ubuntu only started in terminal mode and I couldn't get `startx` command to run too. The startx command ended up by open a CLI with white screen. Right now, I ran "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" but I dun know how to enable it or activate it.

Can anyone please kindly brief me about that? Between, my internet connection is bad, so that I wonder is there any alternative way in order to complete update or upgrade in this portion?

p/s: Currently my ubuntu ver is 12.04.1 and I dun think to have a clean install. Because I backup the ubuntu into virtual hardisk with some software well installed and also configured. The installers of those software are not with me. So what I can do is only troubleshooting or do some update or upgrade.

The snapshot on results of startx and Xorg.0.log attached as below:

[Xorg.0.txt](http://summerap.com/Xorg.0.txt)

[image]

Comment: you want to install Ubuntu-desktop through CLI or  just do an update.

Comment: update, in order to switch to graphic mode.

Comment: I don't think the problem here really has anything to do with what packages are installed. That is, I think you have all the necessary software installed for a GUI, but that the GUI is just not *working* for some reason. *How* did you install Ubuntu? What *version* of Ubuntu did you install? What happens if you try to boot it with the [`nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) boot option? What happens if you run `sudo start lightdm`? Please **edit your question** again, to provide this information.

Comment: unknown job: lightdm. There is no installation. Instead, it is a virtual hardisk. How can I boot via nomodeset? Appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to install this specific package (**ubuntu-desktop**) without an internet conection because yours it's slow.

Try to use the Ubuntu disc as a repository (to install the **ubuntu-desktop** package):
insert your ubuntu disc to reader then type:

```
sudo apt-cdrom add
```

This should add it to the **sources.list file**. Leave the disc inside the disc reader and then try:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you type:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will upgrade the whole system.

Comment: Ic, thanks for your sharing. Appreciate if you can assist me regarding to the portions that I updated above.

Comment: One thing I wonder is if I upgrade the ubuntu through cdrom, then after this, will I get the graphic mode?

Comment: If you want to upgrade using the disc, then why not do a clean install? I think it would be safer and better than reinstall over your actual system. The ubuntu-desktop package should be installed by default and it will give you the hability to access through GUI. Obviously the `startx` command only can be used after installing the ubuntu-desktop package.

Comment: Update your question with more info such as your current OS version and the one you want to upgrade.

Comment: On a regular ubuntu installation, the easy way to switch between the CLI and GUI is pressing one of the following shortcuts:

For use one of the six terminals:

Ctrl+Alt+F1,
Ctrl+Alt+F2,
Ctrl+Alt+F3,
Ctrl+Alt+F4,
Ctrl+Alt+F5 or Ctrl+Alt+F6

To use the GUI:
Ctrl+Alt+F7

Comment: Clean install is impossible. Because all the softwares and data is backup via virtual hardisk. What I can do is only troubleshooting. I have ubuntu-desktop installed, but the startx command ended up with a small CLI with white screen.

Comment: lightdm and gdm command not found. and startx ended up by the snapshot as attached above.

Comment: Try this: `sudo service gdm start` or `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: tried before. same goes with unrecognized service.

Comment: Try to find if the GDM or LightDM service is installed in your system: `cd /etc/init.d` then the following command to see if it's there: `ls -l`

Comment: not found for GDM and LightDM but I did install the ubuntu-desktop. Wondering.

Comment: Are you sure that ubuntu-desktop was already installed on your system?, because it's doesn't seem to be.

Comment: yes, I did execute "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop" before this. but perhaps installation not successful or what I am not sure as you said it's doesn't seem to be. I checked through "dpkg -l ubuntu-desktop" and the package not found. If the ubuntu desktop is well installed, when execute the dpkg, definitely there will be an entry for ubuntu desktop, am I right?

Comment: `dpkg -l ubuntu-desktop` is just another way to execute .deb files. How are you trying to install ubuntu-desktop? from the internet or adding your ubuntu disc as a repository? this is very important to understand why the package isn't there. Have you tried switch to GUI using the shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+F7?

Comment: another way to execute .deb files? What for the .deb file? I thought is used to verify status of installation? I installed the ubuntu-desktop through internet. For those shortcut key like ctrl+alt+(1-7), all no response, dun know why.

Answer (score 0):

You should update using terminal window with `sudo apt-get update`   and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: this one requires internet connection isn't?

Comment: yes it does require internet connection , do you already have Ubuntu desktop installed or Ubuntu server . Try to add that info in Question.

Comment: Actually quite complicated for my case as I researched through many sites and did many steps to fix it. But unfortunately, failed at the last. You can refer my edited post for further details. Much Appreciate.